# Forbid an API in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, log4j

I'm running two Java programs from within MATLAB, which means they both share the same JVM instance with MATLAB.  This is a problem when trying to use Log4J, because it's statically configured.  If I run PROG1 (and it configures Log4J), then run PROG2 (which also tries to configure Log4J), then PROG2 subsequently fails to log its output to the correct place in certain versions of MATLAB.

I want to somehow configure PROG1's project in Eclipse to forever forbid the use of Log4J, but it should still be allowed in PROG2.  Just removing log4j.jar from the PROG1 project's classpath doesn't solve the problem, because there's no way to prevent it from being re-added as a direct or indirect dependency.

Ideally, it would be nice if I could configure the project so Eclipse will always check for this at compile-time and add markers (like its existing compile warnings & errors), and tag any Log4J accesses (including our own utility classes for configuring Log4J) in that project with a brief message explaining this problem.

The next best thing I can think of is to further complicate the Ant script, but that still leaves open the possibility that I or someone else in the future might add Log4J logging to the PROG1 project and not realize the consequences until after spending a significant amount of time and later running a build.

Any ideas how I can forever forbid the use of Log4J in a specific project, such that it's also adequately protected from the same problem in the future?

Comment: Make it so the Log4J jar's aren't included in PROG1?

Comment: As far as the Eclipse approach goes, you could remove Log4J from the build path of the project you're compiling. That would turn every Log4J reference into an unresolved one that Eclipse would report.

Comment: As I stated in the question, just removing Log4J from the build path is not sufficient for 2 reasons: 1. Some of this project's project dependencies include and export Log4J as a dependency. 2. Log4J is our go-to logging API for all our other projects, and I want to prevent anyone from re-adding Log4J in the future.